# java SecurityManager denies explicitly allowed permissions on some systems

Tags: java, permissions, wildfly-10, java-security-manager

I am running an application with `Drools` in a `WildFly 10.1.0-Final` Application Server. As the code executed by `Drools` is untrusted, I decided to build a custom sandbox to allow for secure execution.

Since no external modules may be added to the Application Server, I decided that, to effectively use this sandbox, I'd have to create a fitting environment.

So, in the `standalone.xml` of the server, I defined a `maximum-set` and a `minimum-set` of permissions for all wars, which I set to `java.permission.AllPermission`, thereby generally allowing all code to be executed.

I then added the `-secmgr` flag to the server, to activate the SecurityManager. I was able to use the application as intended, and several calls to `AccessController.doPrivileged()` did indeed check the permissions and allowed the desired actions.

I then created a Service class, which would create a Sandbox-context to check the access against.

It explicitly creates an `AccessControlContext` with a `CodeBase` of `null` (meaning ALL code) and a `ProtectionDomain` with three necessary Permissions for Drools - `Runtime.getClassLoader`, `Runtime.accessDeclaredMembers` and `Reflect.suppressAccessChecks`. I then  call `AccessController.doPrivileged` with the desired call (`StatefulKnowledgeSession.fireAllRules`) and the Sandbox Context.

On my development system, when a drools rule tries to do anything not permitted (say, creating a File), a `ConsequenceException` is thrown with an `AccessControlException` as cause, due do denied Access to `File.write`.

On our production system, the same configuration and deployment is used, yet all calls fail due to an `AccessControlException` which states that `Runtime.getClassLoader` is not permitted.

I debugged the live system, when calling `sandboxContext.checkPermission(new RuntimePermission("getClassLoader"))`, no exception is thrown, which tells me that the context itself allows it.

Still, our production machine denies the permission

The only difference in the systems is the OS-Version, as I am using an `Ubuntu` machine and the production server is a `CentOS` machine.

**UPDATE**

Debugging the server found, that there is another `ProtectionDomain` that is unsigned and for no code base, and that one is missing the `Runtime.getClassLoader` permission. However, that particular `ProtectionDomain` is not present on my development machine, and I have no way of finding where that one comes from.

**UPDATE 2**

More information:
When the exception is thrown, the AccessControlStack contains a privileged context (the one I instantiated and expected) and 5 extra `ProtectionDomain`s. One of these (the offending one) has, as said before, a `CodeSource` of `(null <no signer certificates>)`, has no Principals, has a `null` `PermissionCollection` and uses the `org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader`.

The Permissions granted by this Domain (taken from `domain.toString()`):

```
("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:0" "listen,resolve")
("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:0" "listen,resolve")
("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "path.separator" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.separator" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "line.separator" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor.url" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.class.version" "read")
("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "stopThread")
("javax.security.jacc.WebRoleRefPermission" "" "**")
("javax.security.jacc.WebRoleRefPermission" "Faces Servlet" "**")
("javax.security.jacc.WebRoleRefPermission" "metaform" "**")
("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/")
```

This clearly does not have `Runtime.getClassLoader`, however, according to the docs I read, since I grant that permission via `doPrivileged`, that should not matter at all.

I see that the ApplicationServer uses Wildfly-Elytron 1.0.2.Final for its SecurityManager - is it possible that Elytron does not implement this behavior?

**UPDATE 3:**

A third developer machine was used to check, and that one fails, too. As this machine also uses Ubuntu, we can safely say that `CentOS` is **not** the cause here.

**UPDATE 4:**

As you can see, the granted permissions are roughly the same as the default `java.policy` permissions, which should not even be used anymore, according do Wildfly Docs.

We found that the `org.jboss.security.jacc.DelegatingPolicy` seems to delegate to the Permissions as defined in `java.policy` instead of `standalone.xml`.

Comment: `doPrivileged` can't be used to elevate *future* callers' privileges, only past ones'. Alternative: Package the library autonomously server-side, and use whatever WildFly-specific config to grant the necessary permissions to just that JAR's domain. But: a) The lib may need to be security-aware, i.e., use `doPrivileged` itself when necessary. b) If the AS employs a `SecurityManager` that doesn't unconditionally delegate permission checking to threads' ACCs (which seems to be the case with `WildFlySecurityManager`), then the lib may be forced to use its proprietary equivalent of `doPrivileged`.

Comment: Side note: `RuntimePermission("accessDeclaredMembers")` and `ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")` are, at least under a standard `SecurityManager`, considered *sandbox-defeating* permissions. Think twice before granting them.

Comment: Thank you for these insights, they do help in understanding the whole security architecture.

For the side note, I don't think I can remove those, as they are needed by drools, I think it's just the classloader though. Do you have any ideas how to grant those explicitly to the classloader, while disallowing for everyone else?

Comment: I have no idea whatsoever what Drools is and how it works. Initially I understood that you aim to sandbox Drools itself, while you had stated explicitly that your goal is to sandbox code executed *by* Drools. Silly me. Ignore my comment suggesting that Drools be relocated outside the application archive.

Comment: Have you seen ["How to define a KIE Policy"](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_howtodefinekiepolicy)? Does it apply to your setup?

Comment: Generally speaking (and always assuming that WildFly's security manager doesn't do something radically different), permissions are per-domain, not per-class. Thus, to assign different permissions to different classes, a necessary first step is to ensure that they are assigned non-equivalent domains (where equivalence is determined based on their corresponding `CodeSource`s). One way to achieve that is through separate packaging, hence the initial suggestion. Another is by employing different class loaders, or a single custom one that is capable of assigning multiple domains.